# How can I convert String to Date in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, phpmyadmin

I'm a web designer, new to php/sql/phpMyAdmin, but learning fast.

I have imported data with the column "Entry_Date" in the following incorrect format:  (mm/dd/yyyy) Which I now need converted to the correct DATE format/type.

I have set up 2 columns
1) Entry_Date - char(10)
2) New_Date - date

In phpMySql, int the myTable's "SQL" tab, I ran;

```
UPDATE myTable(New_Date)
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(Entry_Date,'%m/%d/%Y') as date FROM `myTable`;
```

I confirmed the SELECT STR_TO_DATE line is successfully converting the string to DATE,  but I am not able to get those values to UPDATE the New_Date column (which is already populatred with "0000-00-00".  What am I missing?

Comment: what was the error you got ?

Comment: #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Also the New_Date column as a DATE-type currently store this value:  0000-00-00 for each row.  So I'm wondering if it requires an UPDATE command instead of the INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT STR_TO_DATE(Entry_Date,'%Y-%m-%d')  FROM `myTable`;
```

or this

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Entry_Date,'%Y-%m-%d')  FROM `myTable`;
```

edit:

```
  UPDATE myTable SET New_Date = DATE(DATE_FORMAT(Entry_Date,'%Y-%m-%d')) ;
```

Comment: Each of those produce this error ->  #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Also the New_Date column as a DATE-type currently store this value:  0000-00-00 for each row.  So I'm wondering if it requires an UPDATE command instead of the INSERT.

Comment: Well the syntax produced no errors, but "0 rows affected", so New_Date values remain "0000-00-00"

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference, but Entry_Dates are in this format (mm/dd/yyyy),  NOT (mm-dd-yyyy).  Updated original post.

Comment: I did not put the 0000s in there,  they were in "New_Date" by default, when I selected DATE as the field type.

Comment: " UPDATE myTable SET New_Date = DATE(DATE_FORMAT(Entry_Date,'%Y-%m-%d')) "  -  This processed with no errors, but did NOT update the "New_Date" field, which still displays 0000's.

Comment: try with `STR_TO_DATE` instead of `DATE_FORMAT` .

Comment: Yea, I tried both already. I even tried changing the New_Date type to varchar, just to see if it would update 'unrestricted' values,  ..nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) with MariaDB.

1. In my situation, the `date` field data type is set to `year`. `strYear` is the datafield that contains the year as a four digit string.
2. Ran the code below. The code was run from the phpMyAdmin SQL page.

   UPDATE `tblBookList`
   SET `BookYear` = [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)(`strYear`, '%Y-%m-%d' ) ;

[MySQL to SQL Server Data Type Comparisons](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2203/mysql-to-sql-server-data-type-comparisons/)

Answer (score 0):

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(entry_date), '%d %M,%Y') as new_date
```